# Can't compile Java-8 source code with Ant v1.9.4 in (CLI)

Tags: java, ant

I can't compile following with JDK8 & Ant v1.9.4 with CLI.

**build.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project default="Compile">
    <target name="Compile">
        <mkdir dir="classes"/>
        <javac
            srcdir="src"
            includes="**/*.java"
            destdir="classes"
            source="1.8"
            target="1.8"
            debug="false">
        </javac>
    </target>       
</project>
```

**Error:**

```
ction.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                             userId= Long.parseUnsignedLong(uid);
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method parseUnsignedLong(String)
    [javac]   location: class Long
    [javac] 1 error
```

> BUILD FAILED E:\dbcommon\build.xml: 176: Compile failed; see the
>   compiler error output for details.

Of course the package exists and it works within Eclipse, but not with the CLI! I only have this JDK installed, no other version, `JAVA_HOME` is set to JDK (not the included JRE)!

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Make sure you point at 1.8 and not any other JDK. This method is @since 1.8

Comment: When building stuff with ant, it is not the ANT version that really matters. It is the version of the JDK that will be used by ANT to build! And obviously, it builds with a pre-1.8 JDK. So just run ant with "-v" to get verbose output.

Comment: Could you share the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: What is your JAVA_HOME path?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

Comment: Yes I got it I have Set PATH as jdk1.8 but JAVA_HOME as a jdk-1.7, Now I changed to JAVA_HOME to jdk-1.8, Its working

Answer (score 0):

Edit the ANT HOME path in the Eclipse.

Right click on the build.xml file >> Run as >> External tool configurations >> Select the classpath tab.
Now change the ANT Home path from here.

[image]

Comment: Hello Sanjith, I am able to build in Eclipse IDE, but my worry is about cmd

Comment: Ahh sorry, this means you are missing something in your system variable.